# expo-cli не устанавливаются в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, npm, expo, yarn

я устоновил expo-cli на ubuntu с помушю  yarn
получилось вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и как видите несуществующая команда

установил с помощью npm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а получилос вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как установит expo-cli

Comment: Текст присылать лучше в виде текста - искать легче.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. открыл папку Home,
2. с помушю ctrl + h нашел скрытый модулы expo и expo-cli.
3. Удалил их.
4. sudo npm i -g expo-cli

все заработало